# raspberry pi 4 tensorflow installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, hdfs

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi $ python3 detect_picamera.py --model /tmp/detect.tflite --labels /tmp/coco_labels.txt
2019-12-28 17:43:12.464130: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "detect_picamera.py", line 34, in
from tf.lite.interpreter import Interpreter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
```

Installed using pip3

Comment: Are you using virtual environments or anything similar?

Comment: NO, installed directly with pip

Comment: Honestly the only advice I give when it comes to packages and Python versions is: Use Conda (and Anaconda). Did tensorflow install correctly, without any errors?

Comment: @prudhvirajboddu I am facing same issue, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually error in the package when it comes to raspberry 
Use

```
from tensorflow.lite.interpreter import Interpreter
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error might be with your Tensorflow installation. You could try to reinstall Tensorflow. Check out my answer here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107920/114206 to do that.